# Remove Duplicate div class with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, duplicates, removeclass

For some odd reason my website is duplicating a `div` element. Before I try to find the reason why it's being duplicated, I'm looking into a way of temporarily hiding the duplicated `div`.

I've tried the following script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.ms-account-wrapper').eq(1).remove();
 });
```

html:

```
<div class="ms-account-wrapper">1</div>
<div class="ms-account-wrapper">2</div> <---want to remove this one
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Max

Comment: Apologies the code above works...I had forgotton to include the extention: 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js'></script>

Comment: Remove this question if your apologies

Answer (score 8):

Select and `remove()` all elements with the `.ms-account-wrapper` class except the first:

```
$(".ms-account-wrapper:not(:first)").remove();
```

This works regardless of how many `.ms-account-wrapper` elements there are

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/p5vs7gae/)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.ms-account-wrapper:last').remove();
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery selector will return an array of all the elements with that class. You can refer to the second element like you would an index of an array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var _divs = $('.ms-account-wrapper');
  // Ensure there is more than 1
  if (_divs.length > 1)
    _divs[1].remove();
});
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLJdoV).

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.ms-account-wrapper').first().nextAll().remove();
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.ms-account-wrapper').not(':first').remove();
});
```

Working Example (here will remove after 3 seconds for demo purpose)

```js
 setTimeout(function(){$('.ms-account-wrapper').not(':first').remove();},3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms-account-wrapper">1</div>
<div class="ms-account-wrapper">2</div>
<div class="ms-account-wrapper">3</div>
<div class="ms-account-wrapper">4</div>
<div class="ms-account-wrapper">5</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var _divs = $('.ms-account-wrapper');
   // Ensure there is more than 1
   if (_divs.length > 1){
      for(var i=1;i<_divs.length;i++)
          _divs[i].remove();
   }
});
```

you can try this...it works if more than 2 also